# Can't access NTFS file after BSOD. Corruption undetectable by chkdsk?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, ntfs, filesystems, corruption

We have several files on a Windows server that show up in directory listings but can't be accessed. I can take ownership of the files, and the ACL shows that Everyone has read/write/execute access; but I can't open the files. chkdsk finds no problems on the volume.

The server is 64-bit Win 2008 R2 Standard SP1.

We had a BSOD recently on this server, and the files were modified shortly before the crash. The crash wasn't in anything filesystem-related, but I'm thinking it corrupted something in kernel memory and that corrupted the filesystem.

Here is some of what I'm seeing when trying to access file "com2.log":

```
D:\Logs\Application>dir com2*
Volume in drive D is Data
Volume Serial Number is 84D5-FD84

Directory of D:\Logs\Application

09/07/2011  06:57 PM           169,025 com2.log
       1 File(s)        169,025 bytes
       0 Dir(s)  39,320,612,864 bytes free

D:\Logs\Application>dir com2.log

 Directory of \\.

File Not Found

D:\Logs\Application>dir com2.*

Directory of \\.

File Not Found

D:\Logs\Application>cacls com2.log
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.

D:\Logs\Application>more com2.log
Cannot access file \\.\com2

D:\Logs\Application>more com2*
Cannot access file D:\Logs\Application\com2.log
```

(cacls doesn't show the ACL, but I can see it in Windows Explorer.)

It seems like it might be a problem with the extension. `dir com2*` finds it but `dir com2.*` does not.

The file shows up as com2.log in Windows explorer, but when I double-click it, I get this error in Notepad referring to a .txt file extension:

```
Cannot find the \\.\com2.txt file.
Do you want to create a new file?
```

Has anyone seen anything like this before? Any suggestions for troubleshooting?

Comment: I've seen some flaky stuff like this before that a reboot resolved. Have you rebooted the server and tried again?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

COM2 is a reserved keyword, quite literally for the hardware port COM2 and I'm not sure how that file got there in the first place, since Windows won't let you create a file called `COM2.log`. Try it now, you'll get an error message. For fun, also try creating `LPT1.txt`.

According to [Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), the following are all reserved names and should not be used as file names.

> - Do not use the following reserved device names for the name of a file:
>
>   CON, PRN, AUX, NUL, COM1, COM2, COM3, COM4, COM5, COM6, COM7, COM8, COM9, LPT1, LPT2, LPT3, LPT4, LPT5, LPT6, LPT7, LPT8, and LPT9. Also avoid these names followed immediately by an extension; for example, NUL.txt is not recommended.

You might try renaming the file either in explorer or using `ren com2.log somethingelse.log` to see if you can manipulate the file then, however I have a feeling that won't work for the same reason you shouldn't be able to create the file in the first place.

Failing that, if you follow [How to Remove Files with Reserved Names in Windows](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/120716) you should be able to remove the file with the following command. Using the same "fully qualified" path, I imagine you'll also be able to rename the file by using `REN` instead of `DEL`.

> DEL \.\C:\SomeDirectory\com2.log

Comment: Worst case, boot of a linux livecd that supports NTFS.  You should be able to delete from there.

Comment: Yes, that didn't occur to me, but should also be quite effective.

Comment: @Ben: I totally forgot about reserved file names. That takes me back to the DOS days (LOADHIGH, DEVICE=, VSAFE, etc). Thanks for the stroll down memory lane.

Comment: @Joeqwerty, safe mode will do nothing; you just need to use the escaped full path name to bypass the reserved device name.

Comment: Thank you! This solved the problem. That would never have occurred to me. I knew COM1, COM2, LPT1 and so on were reserved names, but I didn't realize it would still be reserved if you added an extension such as com1.log.

Comment: The problem filenames came from cygwin - we were using it to grep through some log files and save the results. I wasn't able to move the files using "move", but Cygwin "mv" did the job. Thanks for the fully-qualified path technique, I'll remember that too.

Answer (score 1):

You might try moving the file: `move com2* com2.log.new` or something of the sort. The filename itself might be messed up.